# Como añadir un estilo cuando haya selección de un option select

Tags: html, jquery

si tengo un select, que quiero que cada vez que seleccionen un option se cambie el color de la fuente del mismo como podría hacerlo.

Es decir si no hay selección que se mantenga blanca, pero si se selecciona cualquier option ya cambie a color negro

```
<select id="servicio" name="marca">
  <option value="Marca">Marca</option>
  <option value="Ropa">Susuki</option>
</select>
```

Así me dice que opción tengo seleccionada, pero no sabría como cambiarle el color

```
$(document).on('change', '#servicio', function(event) {
  console.log($("#servicio option:selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera seria esta creando en css el estilo que quieres para la opcion. Despues por javascript le agregas la clase.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#servicio', function(event) {
  $("#servicio option:selected").addClass('seleccion'); //Esto para cambiar el fondo de la opcion
});
```

```css
.seleccion{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.reset{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="servicio" name="marca">
  <option value="Marca">Marca</option>
  <option value="Ropa">Susuki</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery nos proveé del método .css() que acepta una propiedad y un valor ejemplo:

```
$("#element").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Ahora que si quieres agregar multiples estilos podrias pasarle un objeto al metodo .css(), ejemplo:

```
$("#element").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
```

Para tu caso podría ser

```
$("#servicio option:selected").css("background-color", "yellow");
```